# How do I get multiple namespaces in XML C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xml-namespaces

Following is the XML format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package version="2.0" unique-identifier="isbn0000000000000" xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
<metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
<dc:title>Eltern Family</dc:title>
<dc:creator></dc:creator>
<dc:publisher></dc:publisher>
<dc:rights></dc:rights>
<dc:identifier id="isbn0000000000000">0000000000000</dc:identifier>
<dc:language>de</dc:language>
<dc:date opf:event="publication">2019-02-11</dc:date>
</metadata>
</package>
```

Here I got the default Namespace by `XDocument.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();`. But as you can see, there are multiple namespaces in the `<metadata>` XML node. The problem is that, they are variable i.e., each XML may have different values, so I cannot declare a variable with one fixed value.

How do I get the namespaces, so that I can add values to the descendant elements?

Please help.

Regards
Aman

Comment: I'd be surprised if you're processing XML that matches a certain schema but the namespaces are 'variable'. The namespace is a part of the element / attribute name. Are you sure?

Comment: Sorry, it will not be variable but yes, now that there are multiple namespaces, I need to insert values in <dc:rights>. How do I do that?

I tried declaring the URI in a XNamespace variable and do the following:

`xpackdoc.Root.Element(packagedcNamespace +"dc", "rights")`

It is showing null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you say, you want to set the content of `dc:rights`, then you need to get hold of that element.

You can do this by name - the 'qualified name' is made of of the namespace and a local name. The namespace prefix `dc` is not actually important in and of itself, it's just used as a shorthand to refer to the namespace within the document.

Assuming you have parsed this XML to an `XDocument` called `doc`:

```
XNamespace dc = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"

var rights = doc.Descendants(dc + "rights").Single();

rights.Value = "text";
```